# Programmatically stop and restart express servers (to change ports)

Tags: node.js, express, ports

I'm looking to be able to basically change ports that my express app is running on.

I've tried:

```
server.on('close', function() {
  server.listen(3000);
});

server.listen(8080);
server.close();
```

This returns a cryptic node.js error. I'm running node v0.4.11, I'm upgrading now to see if that fixes it.

**EDIT** Here's the error:

```
Assertion failed: (!io->watcher_.active), function Set, file ../src/node_io_watcher.cc, line 160.
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: `.listen` is asynchronous, so that will try to close before it's open. Try `server.listen(8080, function() { server.close(); });`, maybe that will work.

Comment: Assertion failed: (!io->watcher_.active), function Set, file ../src/node_io_watcher.cc, line 160.

Comment: Actually this is looking like an error in 0.4.11. I've upgraded to 0.7.7 and it seems to be working. @loganfsmyth , good point - I don't think that was the problem here, but that could lead to problems down the road.

Comment: @loganfsmyth actually scratch that. That looks to be the root of the problem. Could you put that into an answer so I can accept it? Thanks man.

Comment: @Matt Glad to help, answer posted.

Comment: FYI: express's server.listen is simply a wrapper for http.server.listen. for people who want to google other solutions.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The issue is that `.listen` is asynchronous. By calling `.close` immediately after calling `.listen`, you are closing it before it has been opened.

Try this instead.

```
server.listen(8080, function() {
  server.close();
});
```

Comment: #close is also asynchronous. It has a callback, which only triggers when server have finished dealing with any leftover connections

Comment: app.close() is not (longer?) part of the express api https://expressjs.com/en/api.html v4

Comment: @HarryMoreno Right, it is part of Node's API https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_close_callback `server` in this question is a Node server that has an express application attached to it. It is not the express `app` itself.

Comment: `server` in this case is probably obtained by listening on the express app as shown in Derek Hill's answer.

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to [@aymericbeaumet](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/1366#issuecomment-68693264), the following snippet works with Express 4:

```
var app = express();

var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening :)');
  server.close(function() { console.log('Doh :('); });
});
```