# Restart Node.js Server after Post Request

Tags: node.js

Is there any way to have your Node.js server restart after completing a POST request? The reason being that API data doesn't persist on the client side when I refresh the browser until the server restarts.

So is there any way to programmatically do this? I've been searching all over for the past couple days and I can't seem to find anything to fit my specific needs.

Hopefully this makes sense! I was trying to convey my question without going too deep in the type of project I'm working on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Express? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959590/programmatically-stop-and-restart-express-servers-to-change-ports

Comment: @mparnisari I am. This definitely points me in the right direction. Thanks!